# Why path of java class file starts with slash (/) on Windows 10?

Tags: java, path, filepath, slash

I'm using `DeviceManager.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()` to get the file path of the DeviceManager class, but it outputs: `/C:/Users/gdiaz/repos/devicetalk/build/classes/main/` as you can see the path start with a forward slash (/).  Why is that happening and how can I fix it?

Then I use that path with `new JarFile(currentPath)` but I'm getting `java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\user\repos\devicetalk\build\classes\main (Access is denied)` but since the path starts with `/` it throws that exception.

I'm running Intelli J 2020.3 on Windows 10.
SKD corretto-1.8.0_275.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but paths starting with forward-slash (`/`) seem to be normal and it really doesn't cause problems. I thought the `FileNotFoundException` was because of the `/` at the start of the path but it turns out that the specified path is not a file but a directory. Dumb mistake.